# Filter by a week yesterday

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
df
0   2021-08-01    20
1   2021-09-01    10
...
20  2021-17-01    18
```

How can I keep only dates between yesterday (16th Jan) to a week before yesterday (10th Jan) in general code? I tried:

```
df[df.date >((datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta (1)) - pd.timedelta("7day")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `pd.DateOffset` and create some boolean statements to filter your dataframe.

### solution

```
yesterday = pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.DateOffset(1,'D')
one_week_from_yesterday = yesterday - pd.DateOffset(7,'D')
date_filter = df['date'].le(yesterday) & df['date'].ge(one_week_from_yesterday)
df1 = df[date_filter]
```

or as `@Shubham Sharma` has noted use `Series.between`

```
df1 = df[df['date'].between(one_week_from_yesterday,yesterday)]
```

### setup.

```
import pandas as pd 
d = pd.date_range('01 Jan 2021', pd.Timestamp('now'),freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : d})

print(df)

      date
0  2021-01-01
1  2021-01-02
2  2021-01-03
3  2021-01-04
4  2021-01-05
5  2021-01-06
6  2021-01-07
7  2021-01-08
8  2021-01-09
9  2021-01-10
10 2021-01-11
11 2021-01-12
12 2021-01-13
13 2021-01-14
14 2021-01-15
15 2021-01-16
16 2021-01-17
```

---

```
yesterday = pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.DateOffset(1,'D')
one_week_from_yesterday = yesterday - pd.DateOffset(7,'D')


date_filter = df['date'].le(yesterday) & df['date'].ge(one_week_from_yesterday)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15     True
16    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

---

```
 df[date_filter]

 date
8  2021-01-09
9  2021-01-10
10 2021-01-11
11 2021-01-12
12 2021-01-13
13 2021-01-14
14 2021-01-15
15 2021-01-16
```